# Is there any way to know why SPMetal is not generating classes?

Tags: development, web-part, linq, spmetal

Running SPMetal on Sharepoint site or any of its subsites returns

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Is there a log or any way to find out what's going wrong? I cant seem to generate classes

I am using Sharepoint 2013 and a Webpart in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint write the logs (called ULS) on the server. if you have access to the server then you can checked it from there.

- go to the  central admin site --> Monitoring --> Configure diagnostic logging. on this page you will see the path of the logs file.
- if you have multiple servers then you have to collect logs from all server. there is a command which can merger log file from all server in one file. you can user [Merge-Splogfile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
- To read the files in good way you can use [ULS viewer tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020)